# Return Text Status From Function

Tags: r, function, loops, time

I am trying to create a function that will do a couple of things.  First it will check a couple of tables to see if workflows have been completed or not and then return a status message one way or the other.  This is easy enough.  However there is an issue that if the ETL's are disrupted the status table does not get updated.  As a result if the script is kicked off manually it will fail.

I want to insert logic into the function to check the system time and if it is after 7:00 AM, skip the check and run the rest of the script.  Here is what I have right now.  It works fine after my cut-off time, but when I set the variable to less than seven for testing I get no status message back.

```
run_time <- as.numeric(format(Sys.time(),"%H"));
run_time <- 4

wrkflw_check <- function(m) {
    bk <- 36
    msg <- "stoped checking"

    if (run_time > 7) {
        msg <- "Complete"
    }
    else {
      # loop until workflows complete or 3 hours. Which ever comes first
      for (i in 1:bk) {
      if ((etl_check$status == "wait") | (dl_check$status == "wait")) {
        Sys.sleep(300)
        etl_status <- paste0("etl status: ", etl_check$status)
        dl_status <- paste0(" dl status: ", dl_check$status)
        print(etl_status)
        print(dl_status)
        etl_check <- dbGetQuery(fm01, etl_sql)
        dl_check <- dbGetQuery(dl, dl_sql)
        i <- i + 1
      } else {
        i <- bk
        msg <- "Complete"
      }
    }
}}

msg <- wrkflw_check(m);

etl_check <- dbGetQuery(fm01, etl_sql)
dl_check <- dbGetQuery(dl, dl_sql)
```

What I need to get back is the msg variable.

Comment: (a) You should work on your indentation - it will make your code much easier to read. (b) In an R `for` loop, you shouldn't increment `i` manually, instead to go to the next iteration use the key word `next`. (c) You should use `return(msg)` to return `msg` whenever you want to end your function. (d) You should probably make `run_time` an explicit argument of your function, rather than having your function just go looking for it in the global environment.

Comment: I just fixed your indentation for you (to be consistently 2 spaces/level). It makes it much clearer to see the `if {...} else {...}` pairs.

Comment: I inserted the return statements and put the run_time into the function, neither one made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to break things up a little to get what I wanted.  But this works now.

```
wrkflw_check <- function(m){
    bk <- 36
    msg <- "stoped checking"
# loop until workflows complete or 3 hours. Which ever comes first
    for (i in 1:bk) {
        if ((etl_check$status == "wait") | (dl_check$status == "wait")) {
            Sys.sleep(300)
            etl_status <- paste0("etl status: ", etl_check$status)
            dl_status <- paste0(" dl status: ", dl_check$status)
            print(etl_status)
            print(dl_status)
            etl_check <- dbGetQuery(fm01, etl_sql)
            dl_check <- dbGetQuery(dl, dl_sql)
            i <- i + 1
        } else {
            i <- bk
            msg <- "Complete"
            return(msg)
        }
    }
}


run_time <- as.numeric(format(Sys.time(),"%H"));
#run_time <- 4
run_time

if (run_time > 7) {
    msg <- "Complete"
} else {
    msg <- "incomplete"
    msg <- wrkflw_check(m)
};
```